# Once SSHd into my windows laptop, Putty doesn't recognize python

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, putty

I'm SSHing from a mac into my windows laptop which has PuTTY on it.  I can SSH in just fine, and everything seems to work, except for python.  When I type in 'python myfile.py' I get the error "-bash: python: command not found" if I'm in the terminal window that is all colorful from PuTTY, and if I type in "cmd" to switch to the Command Window, the error I get is "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
I have already gotten python to work on the Windows computer when I am not SSH'ed into it.  So, I have already put Python27 into the Environment Variables.

I have found that if I type in "/cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe myfile.py", it will run, but I would like to be able to just type in "python".
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: that's not putty's fault. that's the fault of the shell used by whatever account you're logging into via putty.

Comment: Then how do I change the shell?

Comment: figure out what shell is (bash, sh, zsh, etc...), find its corresponding `rc` file, (e.g. `/etc/bashrc`?) and add python's location to the PATH environment var.

Comment: Also, I already added python's location to the PATH environment var.  Is there another PATH environment var that I'm supposed to add it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I found this link: http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/prog/cygwin/FAQs.html#bashrc  which really helped.
I went to the /usr/bin folder, then typed 
ln -s /cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe

and now I can type "python myfile.py" when ssh'd through PuTTY and it works!

Comment: I also did this for java, which works, except that the -cp isn't working properly, but that is more likely to be my fault - I'm probably just doing something wrong.

Comment: Yep, I was being stupid... I have to replace the ":" with ";"

Comment: But it only works while the computer is on.  Once it is turned off, and then I turn it on again, it doesn't work anymore